# One picture doesn't show up properly online, in local view is everything ok

Tags: html, css, image, server, hosting

I have a problem with only ONE picture in a list of pictures, when picture is showing up in "offline mode" but not after uploading to the hosting. I used same code for every article or picture on the site. Every picture is made and saved in the same way as others. I'm completely at a loss (or blind) so I decided to ask you. Thanks for every help.

Here is the used code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="6u">
<section class="special">

<a target="_blank" href="pdf/minidis.pdf" class="image fit"><img src="images/minidis.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<h3>MINIDIS ADXpert</h3>
<p>Přenosný a automatický destilační přístroj</p>
<ul class="actions">
<li><a target="_blank" href="pdf/minidis.pdf" class="icon fa fa-file-pdf-o major small"></a></li>
</ul>
</section>
</div>

<div class="6u">
<section class="special">

<a target="_blank" href="pdf/ad6.pdf" class="image fit"><img src="images/ad6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<h3>AD-6</h3>
<p>Automatický destilační přístroj pro stanovení destilační křivky</p>
<ul class="actions">
<li id="skok3"><a target="_blank" href="pdf/ad6.pdf" class="icon fa fa-file-pdf-o major small"></a></li>
</ul>
</section>
</div>
```

U can see a problem here:
[Website](http://www.poly-analyser.cz/lab.html)

It's about article named "AD-6"

Comment: Where is the missing image ? I can see your all 18 products on the website

Comment: @tektiv Oh really? O_____o It's AD-6 item (6th picture)

Comment: It’s probably blocked by an ad-blocker, because the file name contains the word “ad”.

Comment: Oh GOD, it's ad-block, thank you rly for your help and for your time guys!

Comment: @FilipOrlt Yep, look at [this image](http://imgur.com/aPysf85). Btw Xufox may be right, your AdBlocker may be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

Image contains **"ad"** in its name and **"ad-blocker"** blocks this image as ad.

Thank you guys for help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this inline style from your image tag{display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 0px 0px;}

Comment: Style is ok, thanks for your time, it was due to name "ad6" which is blocked by ad-block app.